# Can dry aging beef and curing/fermenting/drying meat be done in same environment?

Tags: meat

Can dry aging beef and curing/fermenting/drying meat be done in same environment ? By environment I’m referring to using the same fridge or room for example. Do these processes require similar temperature and humidity ? I’d like to get a dry aging fridge, but maybe I would need two if I want to do it all (dry age beef and make salami).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do both in the same environment because the two need very different temperatures. Dry aging beef requires a cold environment (34-38°F or 0-2°C). Curing salami needs a higher temperature (42-60°F, 6-16&dev;C) and slightly higher humidity (70-80%). Beef would rot in the temperature range you'd cure salami.